# download mysql slow query log on google cloud sql

Tags: mysql, slow-log, google-cloud-sql

I'm having a difficult time locating the log file to download.  When running

```
show global variables like '%slow%';
```

I can see it is located

```
/mysql/logs/slow.log
```

When I log into the instance though that path doesn't exist.  Any ideas?

This is through google cloud sql and using mysql as the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found an answer.  It is not perfect as the quality of data may need some massaging, but it works.

```
gcloud logging read projects/yourproject/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql-slow.log --format json| jq -rnc --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)) | .textPayload' > slow-log-timestamp.log
```